# Is there a way to not have a blank cell considered 0 in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

New to vba and trying to do something very basic. I have a column full of numbers that also contains blank cells. When I try to do this If statement, Excel considers the blank cells as the value 0. I only want the cells with numbers to have the "Alerted Transaction" value, not the blank cells. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
If Columns("J").Value > 0 Then Columns("J").Value = "Alerted Transaction"
```

Comment: Well that line would throw an error, but you can test if the cell is blank using `IsEmpty`. You could also filter. Note - use `IsEmpty` on a single cell, not a multi-cell range.

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J1:J10").Cells 
    If Not IsEmpty(c.Value) Then c.Value = "Alert" 
Next
```

As @BigBen pointed out, you probably don't want to `IsEmpty` the whole column, this code checks Row 1 to Row 10 in Column J. You may adopt the code to your scenario accordingly.

See [doc on IsEmpty](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/isempty.php) and [doc on For loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/looping-through-a-range-of-cells)

Comment: @BigBen quite right thanks for pointing it out. I don't have Excel on hand, so I'll leave the fun to OP.

Comment: Good edit (btw not my downvote). Though the `.Cells` is redundant.

Comment: @B.Gao you almost solved my problem. I added a "Not" after my If to solve my problem. I think I may have worded my question incorrectly.

Comment: I see, sorry I didn't read the logic carefully. You are right, if it is not-is-empty you wish to alert the user of, then that's the way to do it. Glad your problem is solved. Updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Define the range you want to check, loop each cell in the range and check for empty cells.

```
dim myWS As Worksheet
set myWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("myWorksheet")

With myWS
   Dim loopRange As Range
   set loopRange = .Range(.Cells(2,10),.Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count,10))
End with
dim currCell As Range
for each currCell in loopRange
   if currCell.Text<>vbNullString Then
      currCell.Offset(0,3).Value = "Alerted Transaction"
   end if
next
```

There are better ways to get the last populated cell in a column, but that is for another day :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if a cell is empty by using the
`IsEmpty` function. I don't really mess around with Excel so I don't know how you would check a range of cells.